# Different Response based on ACL with FOS Rest Bundle

Tags: symfony, acl, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I search for a best practice method how I can send different users, different responses back based on the ACL from Symfony.

I use the FoS RestBundle. They provide the JMSSerializerBundle which I use. I've created models and serializer yml-files, so far, so good. Everything looks great and works.

Now I have different Users that access this REST API. Some of them have expanded permissions, so they are allowed to see more information. What is the best practice for handle them?

It's necessary that the URL is the same for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by using serialization groups:
http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-serialization-groups

After that you can choose which group you want to your response:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/serializer.html

You can still use the same YML you are using:
http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/yml_reference

Check the groups attribute!

This should be enough, if you need more acl as well:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html

Good luck, I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks @johnSmith :)

Comment: Thank's for your fast and clear answer. :-)
I will try it tomorrow at work, i hope it works under symfony 2.5.10 :/

Comment: I'm not sure about it! But you can use the JMS solutions standalone in that case, by calling the serializations calls manually or even registering a new kernel response event

Comment: Unfortunately, my team leader has stepped up another part of the project, so I will come later to test your solution. But you'll get definitely provide feedback if I've tested it.